# Get real position in lexer. with example

Tags: netbeans-7, netbeans-platform, antlr4

I writing editor with netbeans7 and ANTLR4
I have line in my.g4 file

```
Label       : {(getCharPositionInLine()==0)}? ID;
```

That works well for static files, but while editing getCharPositionInLine() returns 0 often in other places.
How get a real position in lexer?

I noticed that, while editing text editor sent to lexer not all text but only changed, and in this fragment working lexer. I don't know how change it.

I created example with this problem
https://github.com/daimor/SimpleANTLR

Answer (score 1):

If your input stream does not represent a stream starting at the beginning of the file, then you need to initialize the lexer with the line/column where the stream is actually starting.

```
lexer.getInterpreter().setLine(actualLine);
lexer.getInterpreter().setCharPositionInLine(actualCharPositionInLine);
```

If you do not do this, the lexer will always assume that the input stream starts at the beginning of the file.

Comment: Well, but I don't know, how get actualLine and actualCharPositionInLine

Comment: Since you aren't using one of the standard input streams (e.g. `ANTLRFileStream`), that's application specific. That information needs to be *provided* to ANTLR, and it appears you'll need to get it from NetBeans in some way.